# Using specific fonts in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to use specific fonts in my LaTeX file. But `fontspec` can't find my desired fonts. I use

```
family file | grep -i helvetica
```

to know the names to use in XeTeX using `fontspec`

```
/usr/local/share/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-UltLtIt.otf: Helvetica Neue LT Pro,HelveticaNeueLT Pro 25 UltLt
/usr/local/share/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn.otf: Helvetica Neue LT Pro,HelveticaNeueLT Pro 57 Cn
/usr/local/share/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf: Helvetica Neue LT Pro,HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt
```

My `.cls` part that needs specific fonts is

```
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 25 UltLt}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 57 Cn}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt}
```

But `fontspec` gives errors all the time!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We can't help you unless you tell us specifically what errors you're getting.

Comment: And perhaps a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Note that, if these lines are indeed the problem, you can copy them into such a minimal file with no issues.

Comment: The error is "font-not-found". The font "HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt" cannot be found.

Comment: I think I'll need change the font names in my LaTeX file.. but I don't know what to do, because I really expect that these names work..

Comment: Did you tried the file name without extension? E.g. `HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt`.

Comment: Wow! Works perfect.. Problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the extensions not the key, rather using the font file name in place of the 'friendly' name (which doesn't work so reliably)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the PostScript name, usually it's the same as the filename sans extension, but not always --- use a font information utility to determine what it is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-UltLt}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Cn}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt}
Main. \bodyfont (bodyfont is same as main)\par
\thinfont Thin.\par
\headingfont Headingfont is condensed.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe interesting: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/4918) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the file name instead of the font name, e.g. for Helvetica Neue LT Pro-Lt 45 Lt.

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt}
```

Comment: With `Ligatures=TeX` instead of `Mapping=tex-text`, the call is compatible with LuaLaTeX.